# Change uvm verbosity during run time of simuation

Tags: uvm

In the simulation, after doing `VCS Save` (For more details: https://blogs.synopsys.com/vip-central/2014/12/30/run-time-save-restore-strategy-with-uvm-vcs/) with verbosity low, I am trying to do `VCS Restore` from the saved checkpoint and run rest of the tests with high verbosity.
While passing `+uvm_set_verbosity="*,_ALL_,UVM_HIGH,run"` through command-line resulted in verbosity low which is the verbosity while creating the saved checkpoint.

Anyone have any suggestion of logging with high verbosity for VCS Save-Restore ?

Comment: Probably the UVM command line arguments, won't work with the save-restore mechanism. The author in the blog also hasn't changed any UVM command line argument.

How about making another `$test$plusargs` for verbosity, like he did for `+seq` ?

Comment: @Karan Shah Can you please explain more on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the UVM infrastructure only reads the plusargs at the start of the simulation.  When you "restore" a simulation, you are effectively starting in the middle of the simulation. Your plusargs don't take effect because the infrastructure knows only about the original plusargs.

If you are going to take this approach, then upon restore, you should manually query the UVM_VERBOSITY plusarg (as well as anything else you might want, for example "what file do I load into RAM?").  Then you do what is required with that information, for-example, you can could call "set_report_verbosity_level_hier()" on your top-level.  (See the code to do this in "uvm_root.svh".)